# unable to get CPP WPTools-(Delphi)-derived components to install in C++Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, tcp, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I'm working with C++Builder XE6 & XE7. I've derived some CPP components from WPTools (Pascal-based) components and have been unable to get them to work with WPTools7, although they worked fine with WPTools6 and earlier versions of XE.

When trying to build my derived CPP components, Builder does not seem to like the passing by reference code it is finding in the WPTools .HPP files.

Lines like the following:

```
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE bool __fastcall WPLocateNextPrev(bool Previous, TParagraph* &active_paragraph, int &active_posinpar, bool &EOF);
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE bool __fastcall WPLocateNext(TParagraph* &active_paragraph, int &active_posinpar, bool &EOF);
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE bool __fastcall WPLocatePrev(TParagraph* &active_paragraph, int &active_posinpar, bool &BOF);``
```

For which I get errors like this:

```
[bcc32 Error] WPRTEDefs.hpp(6117): extern variable cannot be initialized
[bcc32 Error] WPRTEDefs.hpp(6117): Improper use of typedef 'TParagraph'
[bcc32 Error] WPRTEDefs.hpp(6117): Undefined symbol 'active_paragraph'
```

It is not apparent to me that the above declarations in the .HPP code is trying to initialize an extern variable, but please enlighten me if that is the case.

The developer, usually helpful in the past, hasn't been very helpful. I'm not sure if he doesn't know what the problem is or if he just doesn't have any other customers who have tried deriving CPP components the way I have.

If I have to give up my CPP WPTools-derived components, it will probably take a month or more to revise all my code, so I am eager to find a solution if there is one. Does anyone know a fix for this?

It is my impression that it is possible to get the same result as passing by reference in C++ if you simply pass a pointer, so long as you do not deference the variable and explicitly check for the NULL value.

I am thinking about modifying the WPTools7 code to see if bypassing this passing by reference thing would fix the trouble, but as others have developed for Delphi and Builder for so much longer than I have, I thought I'd ask for advice before spending too much time on it.

Since the source is in Object Pascal/Delphi, I'll have to try to figure out what not dereferencing means. I'm sort of the impression that everything in Object Pascal is essentially a pointer, but I'm not entirely sure.

In any case, I thought I'd ask if anyone has ever tried something like this? And/or if anyone has any thoughts about whether or not it would help with my troubles, or create any new ones?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're asking us to solve problems in your "derived components" when we can't see the source for those components. How exactly would that work? We don't have access to the ancestor (WPTools) components, no access to your derived components, no information about the types or classes in the error messages, and no ability to reproduce the issue and try to resolve it. "I have a B, which derives from an A, and I get this error. Please guess what might be causing it." isn't something we can do here.

Comment: Fine. As I all but said, the problem is not with my components with any other version of WPTools, so whatever the problem is, it is new to WPTools7 and the latest versions of XE. And I have no way to know who has done what with what, so I thought there might be someone here who has had similar trouble with these or similar components. But clearly you know better.

Comment: If it's specific to WPTools7, you need to be discussing that with the authors of WPTools. We're not them. :-)

Comment: As I said, the developer has not been all that helpful. And you apparently know for a fact that there is no possibility that anyone here could have had a similar experience using WPTools with C++Builder. Okay, but I thought it was worth a shot. I guess I will know better next time.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think that you @wolfguy deserved the reception you got here. Can you isolate whether the issue is compiler version related or WPTools version related? Always best to change one thing at a time.

Comment: @wolfguy, to answer the question, people need (a) the original declaration of the class you are descending from, (b) your declaration, (c) exact error messages (which you've provided.)  Until we have a, b *and* c no-one can help... To ask a good question, which is one that people will be able to reply, you usually need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Problems with inheriting classes are not going to be specific to WPTools - it's all code - you don't need someone who knows WPTools to answer. You just need to give enough code that anyone who reads code and knows C++Builder can answer.

Comment: Thanks David Heffeman and David M. I commented out the 3 lines I mentioned and everything compiled fine. The developer still insists the code is fine. He has been developing for Delphi for a very long time and his components have always been compatible with C++Builder. He thinks it is a flaw in C++Builder XE6 and XE7 and apparently he doesn't expect Embarcadero to fix it anytime soon. I don't know, but if I don't need that code, I'll just go with it as is.

Comment: As for the reception I got, it's all a matter of opinion I suppose. I was not in a very good mood and did not appreciate what I took to be the tone of the initial response. But maybe my mood was the reason. I don't know. And I guess I did not provide enough information. All I know for sure is that I have been treated with far more respect in other forums even when posting and asking about dumber stuff than this, so I guess, unless I get desperate enough to risk abuse, I will go back to those forums and forget about this one. Anyhow, thanks for the sentiment and the offer to help.

Comment: One last comment to Ken White. Ken, I don't have a chip on my shoulder, but I am a VERY big guy, and I guess I am used to being treated respectfully even when I am being a bit stupid or a bit snarky. Online, it just ain't that way. So maybe that's my "problem." In any case, no hard feelings.

Comment: @wolf You are welcome here. No need to leave already!

Comment: Thanks David. I'll probably lurk some. I don't have much knowledge to impart though. And most of my questions seem to be related to C++Builder weirdness anyhow.